# How do I conditionally set the roles a user can update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 5 roles that a user can have in my rails site

```
- @roles.each do |role|
  %label.radio
    = radio_button_tag 'user[role_ids][]', role.id, @user.has_role?(role.name)
    = role.name
```

And what i want to do is based on the current_user role I wanted to either disable them or hide them altogether

I was thinking of implementing it this way but it doesnt look very clean ....any ideas

I wanted to add this

```
:disabled => disable_role?(current_user, role.name)
```

and

```
def disable_role?(current_user, role_name)
  case  
  when role_name == 'superadmin' and current_user.superadmin?
    return false 
  when role_name == 'admin' and (current_user.superadmin? || current_user.admin?)
    return false 
  when role_name == 'standard' and (current_user.superadmin? || current_user.admin?)
    return false 
  else  
    return true  
  end
end
```

I have other conditions but i wanted to show you an example of my approach 
It seems not so rubylike....any other suggetions

Answer (score 1):

For creating roles I like to use the gem CanCan created by Ryan Bates. He shows how to use it to authenticate on that screencast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan

But if you are going to do it by scratch I used to just add a new method on my user model to verify that to me so everytime it checks if the user has the role that I want

e.g

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def has_hole? role
    self.roles.where(name: role).size != 0
  end
end
```

Comment: but its not just checking if the user has that role....for example an admin user can change a user to admin, standard but not superadmin

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  ROLES_HIERARCHY = ['standard', 'admin', 'superadmin']

  def hierarchy(role_name)
    ROLES_HIERARCHY.index(role_name)
  end
  ...
end
```

And

```
- @roles.each do |role|
  %label.radio
    - if user.role.hierarchy > role.hierarchy
      = radio_button_tag 'user[role_ids][]', role.id, @user.has_role?(role.name) 
      = role.name
```